# Netlify forms not working with my GatsbyJS website

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-form

I am working on a website and using Netlify to host it. I have added Netlify forms into the contact us form in the contact.js file and the form name is showing fine in the Netlify Form dashboard. Although, wheneve I submit the form, nothing happens. No submissions show up on Netlify in either approved or spam.

Here is my contact.js source.

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {graphql} from 'gatsby';

import {Layout} from '../components/index';
import {toStyleObj, withPrefix, htmlToReact} from '../utils';
import FormField from '../components/FormField';

// this minimal GraphQL query ensures that when 'gatsby develop' is running,
// any changes to content files are reflected in browser
export const query = graphql`
  query($url: String) {
    sitePage(path: {eq: $url}) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

export default class Page extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout {...this.props}>
              <article className="post post-full">
                <header className="post-header has-gradient outer">
                  {_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.image', null) && (
                  <div className="bg-img" style={toStyleObj('background-image: url(\'' + withPrefix(_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.image', null)) + '\')')}/>
                  )}
                  <div className="inner-sm">
                    <h1 className="post-title">{_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.title', null)}</h1>
                    {_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.subtitle', null) && (
                    <div className="post-subtitle">
                      {htmlToReact(_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.subtitle', null))}
                    </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </header>
                <div className="inner-md outer">
                  <div className="post-content">
                    {htmlToReact(_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.html', null))}
                  </div>
                  <form name={_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.form_id', null)} id={_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.form_id', null)} {...(_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.form_action', null) ? ({action: _.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.form_action', null)}) : null)}name="contact" method="POST" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field">
                        <div className="screen-reader-text">
                          <label>Don't fill this out if you're human: <input name="bot-field" /></label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value={_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.form_id', null)} />
                        {_.map(_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.form_fields', null), (field, field_idx) => (
                          <FormField key={field_idx} {...this.props} field={field} />
                        ))}
                        <div className="form-submit">
                          <button type="submit" className="button">{_.get(this.props, 'pageContext.frontmatter.submit_label', null)}</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                </div>
              </article>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is very different from Netlify standards. In Netlify, to link your form and the dashboard you need to add some metadata and meta attributes, such as `data-netlify="true"`, `data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"` (to avoid SPAM) and a `name` attribute with exactly the same name than your Netlify form in your dashboard. It must look like:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field">
  {/* You still need to add the hidden input with the form name to your JSX form */}
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
  ...
</form>
```

Take a look at [Form Handling with Static Site Generators](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/) and [How To Use Netlify Forms With Gatsby](https://dev.to/travislramos/how-to-use-netlify-forms-with-gatsby-4c52) (dev.to) articles.

Comment: I have those attributes in the code. They're in the extremely long <form name> tag

Comment: What shows your request in the network tab (in the inspector)?

Comment: Netlify detects it. Whenever I press "Submit" it takes me to a Netlify 404 screen with the same URL as the contact form

Comment: Add an action attribute